# Spring 3.2, jUnit 4.11, JPA NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: expected at least 1 bean

Tags: spring, junit4

I am using annotation based spring configuration and trying to test my JPA based DAO. After configuration, when I ran the test, below error is thrown. I am out of any clue why the IPartnerDao is not found even though a Bean configuration is created in the Test class.

```
    5173 [ERROR] org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager  - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3600e312] to prepare test instance [test.java.net.bornil.persistence.service.partner.PartnerDaoTest@148238f4]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'test.java.net.bornil.persistence.service.partner.PartnerDaoTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private main.java.net.bornil.persistence.service.IPartnerDao test.java.net.bornil.persistence.service.partner.PartnerDaoTest.parDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [main.java.net.bornil.persistence.service.IPartnerDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:379)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private main.java.net.bornil.persistence.service.IPartnerDao test.java.net.bornil.persistence.service.partner.PartnerDaoTest.parDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [main.java.net.bornil.persistence.service.IPartnerDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
        ... 32 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [main.java.net.bornil.persistence.service.IPartnerDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:837)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
        ... 34 more
```

The test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { JPAConfig.class })
public final class PartnerDaoTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public IPartnerDao getParDao() {
            return new PartnerDao();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private IPartnerDao parDao;

    @Test
    public void testFindPartnerWithAddress() throws Exception {
        Partner partner = parDao.findPartnerWithAddress(1L);
        assertNotNull(partner);
    }
}
```

The DAO class

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class PartnerDao implements IPartnerDao {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PartnerDao.class.getName());

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public PartnerDao() {

    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see main.java.net.bornil.persistence.service.IPartnerDao#find(java.lang.Long)
     */
    @Override
    public Partner findPartnerWithAddress(Long id) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Partner ID : " + id);
        }

        Query query = em.createQuery("select p from Partner p join fetch p.addressSet where p.id = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);

        return (Partner) query.getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

The Partner interface

```
@Service
public interface IPartnerDao {

    public Partner findPartnerWithAddress(Long id);

}
```

JPAConfig class

```
@Configuration
// @EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:jdbc.properties" })
public class JPAConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    DataSource getJdbcDataSource() {

        String jdbcUrl = env.getProperty("jdbc.url");
        String username = env.getProperty("jdbc.username");
        String password = env.getProperty("jdbc.password");

        return new DriverManagerDataSource(jdbcUrl, username, password);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(getEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(getJdbcDataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "main.java.net.bornil.persistence.entity" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hjva = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hjva.setGenerateDdl(false);
        hjva.setShowSql(true);
        hjva.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(hjva);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your `JPAConfig.class`

Comment: Added JPAConfig class. The JPA configuration is actually fine because I have tested the application after deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have component scanning setup on your `JPAConfig.class`.

```
@ComponentScan("package.containing.PartnerDao")
public class JPAConfig{

}
```

Also try adding the test to the classes being loaded by the `ContextLoader`

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, 
   classes = { JPAConfig.class, PartnerDaoTest.class })
public final class PartnerDaoTest {

/** tests**/
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. It is working fine as per your suggestion but could you please explain why inner class configuration is not working? I tried the way below too but not working.    `    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("main.java.net.bornil.persistence.service")
    static class ContextConfiguration {
    }
`

Comment: @Mamun so adding that annotation fixed the issue, but the inner class is not loading?

Comment: You are right. I have added another approach in my comment that is also not working.

Comment: @Mamun You could try adding `@Configuration` to your Junit test, but this setup just seems fishy to me, I'm not sure the unit test should contain its own configuration for the IOC container.  This seems to go against the pattern of defining configuration outside of the actual beans, which seems to be the standard approach Spring has adopted with JavaConfig.

Comment: I have actually followed [this blog](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles/).

Comment: @Mamun It looks like he's performing the same in the blog other than he doesn't mix an outside configuration with an internal configuration.

Comment: @Mamun I got one other suggestion, its in my latest update, not sure if this will work

Comment: I think you are right. Mix of configuration could be the problem. I actually tried below way and is working fine. Will try the way you suggested too.    _@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { JPAConfig.class, PartnerDao.class })_

Comment: Adding test to the classes results _java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext_ exception.